# Problems accessing Nextcloud via webdav with gitlab runner

Tags: python, gitlab-ci, webdav, nextcloud

Using pythons webdav.client I connect to a Nextcloud.

```
import webdav.client as wc

def webdav_con(webdav_hostname, webdav_usr, webdav_password):
   options = {
        'webdav_hostname': webdav_hostname, 
        'webdav_login':    webdav_usr,
        'webdav_password': webdav_password,
        'webdav_root': "/remote.php/webdav"
       }
   return client = wc.Client(options)

cloud_client = webdav_con(hostname_webdav_nextcloud, usr_nextcloud, pw_nextcloud)
```

I then list the files in my path and process them afterwards.

```
files_in_cloud = cloud_client.list("path_in_cloud")
```

So far so good - there is no problem when executing the script on my local maschine. The problem arises, when I try to run the script on our gitlab server.

```
webdav.exceptions.RemoteResourceNotFound: Remote resource: path_in_cloud not found
```

Even when I just want to list the files in the root directory I get an error. It seems like I have problems with the authentication which is strange since I use the same credentials/the same url and root as on my local maschine.

```
webdav.exceptions.ResponseErrorCode: Request to my_cloud_url failed with code 401 and message: b'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>\n<d:error xmlns:d="DAV:" xmlns:s="http://sabredav.org/ns">\n  <s:exception>Sabre\\DAV\\Exception\\NotAuthenticated</s:exception>\n  <s:message>No \'Authorization: Basic\' header found. Either the client didn\'t send one, or the server is misconfigured, No \'Authorization: Bearer\' header found. Either the client didn\'t send one, or the server is mis-configured</s:message>\n</d:error>\n'
```

Any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve the issue myself. 
It seems like there is an issue with how webdavclient handles requests under the hood.

Using the new webdav3 client (which uses direct http requests instead of curls) did the trick for me:

```
from webdav3.client import Client 

def webdav_con(webdav_hostname, webdav_usr, webdav_password):
   options = {
    'webdav_hostname': webdav_hostname, 
    'webdav_login':    webdav_usr,
    'webdav_password': webdav_password,
    'webdav_root': r"/remote.php/webdav"
   }


   client = Client(options)

   return client

cloud_client = webdav_con(hostname_webdav_nextcloud, usr_nextcloud, pw_nextcloud)
```

Answer (score -1):

There is a misspelling in 'webdav_root': r"/remote.php/webdav", remove the 'r' to make it work.